# refresh table after file download

Tags: ajax, jsf, download, richfaces

Hi i'm using an h:commandButton to download a file after click like this :

```
<h:commandButton id="getDownload" value="download"  action="#{controller.download()}"   >

</h:commandButton>
<rich:dataTable 
   value="#{controller.listData}" var="category" id="table" >

            <f:facet name="header">
                <rich:columnGroup>
                    <h:column>
                        <h:outputText styleClass="headerText" value="Make" />
                    </h:column>
                </rich:columnGroup>
            </f:facet>
            <h:column>
                <h:outputText value="#{category}" />
            </h:column>

        </rich:dataTable>

 FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) fc.getExternalContext().getResponse();
    out = response.getOutputStream();
```

download is working fine but the rich:datatable is not up-to-date after download
i trying to use the following code but it doesn't work:

```
<h:commandButton id="getDownload" value="download"  action="#{controller.download()}"   >
    <a4j:support event="onclick" disableDefault="true" reRender="table"/>
    </h:commandButton>
```

The h:commandButon is using because we can't download file using ajax 
Someone have any idea how can i refresh my table after button action?

Comment: What's the relation between the data in the table and the downloaded file?

Comment: When we will download file we will add a new line in the table

Comment: I am not sure if you can do this, the `onclick` event is likely happening before the table gets updated and the commandButton has no `oncomplete` event handling.